Embedding gradio in mkdocs throws 404 error
I am having issues in embedding gradio app deployed on HuggingFace spaces inside Mkdocs.
To give you some background - I have a functioning gradio app that is deployed successfully on hubspace. See below an image of it.

I also have a functioning Mkdocs Material website on which I want to integrate this app.
I referred the "Sharing Your App”  documentation from gradio here.
Based on it, I was able to successfully embed my app using iFrame as shown below.

But when I try to do the same using Web Components, it throws an error in the console and renders a blank page as shown below

The error in the console is -
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (index-BeRL9up6.js, line 0)
The Mkdocs logs also show an error as below -
WARNING -  [14:35:24] "GET /assets/external/gradio.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/4.32.0/assets/index-BeRL9up6.js HTTP/1.1" code 404
Note that disabling the Mkdocs Material privacy plugin would load the gradio hugging face spaces embedding as shown below, but still throws errors that I don’t fully comprehend.

Can some kind soul please help me troubleshoot this?
Many Thanks in advance!
